# Appium : Failed to open the application and throwing error Command '/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

Environment

Appium version : 1.6.2 (installed through terminal)
Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue : 1.4.13 (Draco)
OS/version used to run Appium: Mac OS - OS X El Capitan Version : 10.11.6
Mobile platform/version under test: iPad Air iOS 10.1
Device : Simulator

Details

Xcode Version 8.1
Started appium (1.6.2) through Terminal
Ran the script , then I am getting the below error in the error logs
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Command '/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 1 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the carthage and Reinstall it again.